# React : TypeError: this.props.users.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

When I am adding a user and on submitting the user details it is redirecting back to the '/' route(which should display the users with their details) with an error. I've tried checking if the user is present then only do the mapping but it is not working. Can someone please help me to solve this, so that when I redirect back it should display the user that is added. The '/' route displays the List Users Page.

---

Here's the code:

### UserForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'
import Checkbox from './Checkbox'

class UserForm extends Component {
    renderInput(formProps) {
        const className = `field ${formProps.meta.error && formProps.meta.touched ?
            'error' : ''}`
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <label>{formProps.label}</label>
                <input {...formProps.input} type={formProps.type} max={formProps.max} autoComplete='off'
                    label={formProps.label} id={formProps.id}
                    checked={formProps.input.value} />
                {formProps.meta.touched &&
                    (formProps.meta.error && <span>{formProps.meta.error}</span>)}
            </div>
        )
    }

    onSubmit = (formValues) => {
        console.log('formValues', formValues)
        this.props.onSubmit(formValues)
    }


    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props
        const current = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
        let optionsList = [{ id: 1, name: 'Travelling' }, { id: 2, name: 'Reading' }, { id: 3, name: 'Gaming' }]
        const colleges=['Pune University','S.P.College','F.C College']
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
                    className='ui form error'>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>FullName</label>

                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field name='fullname' component={this.renderInput}
                                type='text' className='form-control' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>

                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Address</label>

                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field name='address' component={this.renderInput}
                                type='text' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>

                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>BirthDate</label>

                        <div className='col-sm-10'>
                            <Field name='birthdate' component={this.renderInput}
                                type='date'
                                max={current} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>

                        <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Select Your Gender</label>

                        <div className='col-sm-10 ui radio'>
                            <div className='form-check'>
                                <label className='form-check-label'>Male</label>
                                <Field name='gender' component='input' type='radio' value='male'
                                    className='ui input' />{' '}
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-check'>
                                <label className='form-check-label'>Female</label>
                                <Field name='gender' component='input' type='radio' value='female'
                                />{' '}
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-check'>
                                <label className='form-check-label'>Other</label>
                                <Field name='gender' component='input' type='radio' value='other'
                                />{' '}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                        <label className='col-sm-2 '>Select Your Hobbies</label>
                        <div className='col-sm-10 ui checkbox'>
                            <Field name='roles' component={Checkbox} options={optionsList} type='checkbox' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row mb-3'>
                           <label className='col-sm-2 col-form-label'>Select College</label>
                                <div className='col-sm-10'>
                                    <Field name='college' component='select'>
                                        <option value="">Select a college</option>
                                        {colleges.map(collegeOption => (
                                            <option value={collegeOption} key={collegeOption}>
                                                {collegeOption}
                                            </option>
                                        ))}
                                    </Field>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    <button type='submit' className='ui button'>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

const validate = (formValues) => {
    const errors = {}
    if (!formValues.fullname) {
        errors.fullname = 'You must enter a fullname'
    }
    if (!formValues.address) {
        errors.address = 'You must enter the address'
    }
    if (!formValues.birthdate) {
        errors.birthdate = 'Please select your date of birth'
    }
    if (!formValues.gender) {
        errors.gender = 'Please select your gender'
    }
    if(!formValues.college){
        errors.college='Please select your college'
    }
    return errors
}


export default reduxForm({
    form: 'userform',
    validate: validate
})(UserForm)
```

---

### AddUser.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addUser } from '../../actions'

import UserForm from './UserForm'

class AddUser extends Component {
    onSubmit = (formValues) => {
        console.log('formValues', formValues)
        this.props.addUser(formValues)
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <>
            <div>Add User</div>
            <UserForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, {
    addUser: addUser
})(AddUser)
```

---

### ListUsers.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {listAllUsers} from '../../actions'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class ListUsers extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.listAllUsers()
    }
    usersList(){
        return this.props.users && this.props.users.map((user)=>{
            return (
                <div key={user.id}>
                    <div>{user.fullname}</div>
                    <div>{user.address}</div>
                    <div>{user.birthdate}</div>
                    <div>{user.gender}</div>
                    <div>{user.hobbies}</div>
                    <div>{user.college}</div>
                    <div>{user.roles}</div>
                    <div>
                        <Link to={`/users/edituser/${user.id}`} className='ui button secondary'>Edit</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Link to={`/users/deleteuser/${user.id}`} className='ui button negative'>Delete</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to='/users/adduser' >Add User</Link>
                <h1>Users List</h1>
                {this.usersList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    console.log(state)
    return {users:state.users}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{listAllUsers:listAllUsers})(ListUsers)
```

Comment: try to log `this.props.users` before using it to see what's inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map()` function is available on arrays and it looks like `users` is not one. Check the type of `users` and ensure that it's an array.